Stepper with sub-tasks
I have an enterprise app and it is necessary to group some of the tasks and each group will end with different sub-steps. Like enrolling and sub-task1 ... sub-task2 ... sub-task(n).
We have simplified the process to have the minimal requirements for complete an onboarding process very smoothly. There is a DSL and we have a stepper, however does not include a sub-step environment so one idea is to have the following approach.

Enrollment------------------------2.Training-------------------3.Setting Up---------4.XXX

1.1.Getting badge
1.2.Submit HR documents
1.3.Getting work tools
And each steps is going to have its own sub-steps. How do think of this approach.


Please read these sections in the help center and improve your question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

First use vertical stepper if you can because that is a scaleable design not this horizontal. because in mobile and desktop user can easily scroll vertically rather than horizontally.
Secondly, you can create sub stepper under main stepper just like how the menu item works


Thanks for the response. In this case this approach was rejected because there is a main layout that does not allow the user of left side panels. I had to continue with a horizontal  stepper that could be responsive to the main tasks.

I submitted a component to the DSL in my company and it was well received. The only issue that is bothering me is that is not a scalable option for mobile.
On web this solution is scalable up to n groups and the sub-groups are scalable too. I had to use different nuances to differentiate the status of each tab. Aside of that it is working fine with the users to complete the tasks for this web app.

